# Hot to get the definition of an identifier of a PsiElement?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

In an IntelliJ plugin I'd like to get the value `10` of a `PsiElement` `SOME_CONST` from a source code liek this:

```
package mypackage;
public class Example {
  public void someMethod() {
    otherMethod(SOME_CONST);
  }
...
  private static final int SOME_CONST = 10;
}
```

I have the `PsiElement elem` of `SOME_CONST`. I guess I have to find the references somehow. But I only find empty lists. For example:

```
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent e) {
  ...
  final int offset = editor.getCaretModel().getOffset();
  final PsiElement elem = psiFile.findElementAt(offset);
  final PsiReference[] references = elem.getReferences();
```

`references` has zero length.
Also this does not find anything:

```
  final Query<PsiReference> refs = ReferencesSearch.search(elem);
  final PsiReference ref = refs.findFirst();
```

How do I get to the `10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identifier itself doesn't have any references, so you need to go up the tree using `PsiElement.getParent()` until you find an element that does have references.

`ReferencesSearch.search(elem)` finds references pointing *to* the specified element, which is the opposite of what you need.